# What does \0 mean in sprintf in C?

Tags: c

I have folowing command

```
sprintf(buffer,"file_%i\0,i);
```

what does the \0 do?

Itested it myself and I dont see any difference. Why is it used here?

Comment: Above won't compile. Please provide some [MCVE] that is compiling successfully. Or did you mean `sprintf(buffer, "file_%i\0", i);`  ?

Answer (score 3):

It's a [NUL character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), it's used to denote the end of a string for C-strings. In this case it's completely useless since a string literal (created with `""`) already gets a `\0` appended to it by the compiler.

The `\0` is needed to signal that functions that work with strings to stop when it encounters this character.

Comment: Can you give me an example where its not useless

Comment: @noxusNexus There are none. Not when working with string literals at least.

Comment: @noxusNexus what sombrero chicken is saying is that there is no point to set `\0` in a string literal. They are by definition `\0`-terminated. So you don't gain anything from it, other than for silly tricks like `const char *silly = "This is a sentence\0This is one too";` with which you can have 2 strings on one variable.